# Retrieve 1 specific ax and its component using seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I would like to retrieve 1 specific ax while I use seaborn :
I do this :

```
g = sn.pairplot(df.iloc[:, iloc_col], kind='hist')
```

So I got a fig with a lot of axes (cf https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html)
And I would like to have acces to each axes individually, how can I do?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the 2D array of subplots using `g.axes`:

```
penguins = sns.load_dataset('penguins')
g = sns.pairplot(penguins, hue="species")

# access the lower left axes:
ax = g.axes[-1,0]
ax.annotate('A', xy=(0.5,0.5), xycoords='axes fraction', 
            fontsize=100, weight='bold', color='red', ha='center', va='center')
```

[image]